# Constructing a polyhedron of maximal possible volume from given bounds on areas of its faces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, combinatorial-geometry, computational-geometry, polyhedra

Consider $n$ variables $a_1,...,a_n$ ranging over $\mathbb{R}^+$. Suppose we are given $n$ pairs of positive rational numbers $(p_1,q_1),...,(p_n,q_n)$ where each pair imposes bounds on the corresponding variable: $p_k\le a_k\le q_k$.

Now, suppose we constructed a polyhedron with maximal possible volume, having $n$ faces (indexed in some way) such that the area of $k$-th face lies within the given rational bounds for $a_k$. Let $V_{(p_1,q_1),...,(p_n,q_n)}$ denote the volume of the constructed polyhedron.

- Are polyhedra constructed this way always convex?
- Are $V_{(p_1,q_1),...,(p_n,q_n)}$ always algebraic numbers?

  - If yes, can we narrow down this class of numbers to a smaller one?
  - If no, can we describe in some simple way (without repeating definitions from this post) a countable class of real numbers (preferably, smallest one) such that $V_{(p_1,q_1),...,(p_n,q_n)}$ always belong to this class?
- Is there an algorithm that, given rational bounds $(p_1,q_1),...,(p_n,q_n)$ and a pair of rational numbers $(r, s)$ can decide if $r\le V_{(p_1,q_1),...,(p_n,q_n)}\le s$?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit in your results for your $4 \leq n \leq 8.$

Comment: It may be relevant that (counterintuitively!) the volume of any convex polyhedron can be increased by an isometric deformation to a nonconvex polyhedron. See "[Inflating the cube without stretching](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607754)".

Comment: Perhaps this is what @Will had in mind, but I'd suggest starting by seeing what can be done for tetrahedra.

Comment: The earlier question "[Building a polyhedron from areas of its faces](http://mathoverflow.net/q/82333/6094)," is tangentially relevant (no attempt there to maximize volume).

Comment: @FridaMauer These questions may be related to yours: ["Does every convex polyhedron have a combinatorially isomorphic counterpart whose all faces have rational areas?"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/129677/33698), ["Does every convex polyhedron have a combinatorially isomorphic counterpart whose angles between edges are rational multiples of $\pi$?"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/149286/33698)