# Constructing a Polyhedron given areas of its faces

Tags: polyhedra, surfaces

I want to visualize a set of data as a polyhedron in 3d space. Imagine set A includes areas of such polyhedron's faces. I assume the first step is to check if there exist a polyehdron by making sure each area is larger than the sum of other areas. Then we can perhaps find sets of all normal vectors satisfying such polyhedra by solving:

$\sum A_i\cdot N_i=0$

Up to this point the discussion is provided in an earlier post:
[Building a polyhedron from areas of its faces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82333/building-a-polyhedron-from-areas-of-its-faces)

I do not know what comes next. Assuming we will settle with a unique set of N (for example one that provides the maximum valume), what are the next steps in constructing the Polyhedron? Also what is the best method to find coordinates of vertices/edges to further interact with the resulting Polyhedron?

On a side note: for designers like me with undergraduate background in Mathematics, what programming language do you recommend to visualize data and models built on mathematical algorithms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first effort of which I am aware to reconstruct a polyhedron
from the Minkowski theorem data (face areas and normals) is this old paper; but it was a very nice effort, and explicitly computational:

> Little, James J. "Determining Object Attitude from Extended Gaussian Images." *International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence* (IJCAI). 1985.
>   ([PDF download](https://ijcai.org/Proceedings/85-2/Papers/056.pdf).)
>
> ---
>
> [image: Fig1]

---

Later
Peter Gritzmann and Alexander Hufnagel published an algorithm for polytopes in arbitrary dimension:
"A polynomial time algorithm for Minkowski reconstruction," 1995,
[*Symposium on Computational Geometry*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=220280).
This eventually (1999) became

> "On the Algorithmic Complexity of Minkowski's Reconstruction Theorem,"
>   [*Journal London Mathematical Society*, Volume59, Issue3, pp. 1081-1100](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/59/3/1081.abstract).
>   ([PDF download](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1315603/1315603.pdf).)
>
> "it is shown that this reconstruction problem can be solved in polynomial time when the dimension is fixed but is #P-hard when the dimension is part of the input."

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I was actually hoping to receive a comment from you since I found your answer in the original post very helpful.