# An implementation of Minkowski reconstruction in 3 dimensions

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polyhedra

By a theorem of Minkowski from 1903, an $n$-dimensional polytope $P\subset \mathbb R^n$ is determined up to translation by its unit face normal $u_1,\dots,u_k\in S^{n-1}$ and the corresponding $(n-1)$ dimensional facet areas $a_1,\dots,a_k>0$ that satisfy $\sum_i a_i u_i = 0$.

I am looking for algorithms that actually implement this reconstruction, mainly in 3 dimensions.

This has been discussed in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280921/constructing-a-polyhedron-given-areas-of-its-faces), where a reference to an [article](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1315603/1315603.pdf) of Gritzmann and Hufnagel on the algorithmic complexity of the problem is given. I also found the recent [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.00825.pdf) of Sellaroli, that describes how to reduce the problem in 3 dimensions to a root finding problem of a vector function. It refers to an implementation in a GitHub repository that unfortunately only contains a license text.

Is any actual implementation of an algorithm for Minkowski reconstruction in 3 dimensions available?